# Thunderbolt strike vs grapple

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, grapple, forced-movement

What happens when a creature has grapple as part of their attack (e.g. Constrict from a yuan-ti) attempts to use that on a cleric with the thunderbolt strike ability and has a successful hit?

Does the grapple auto fail? Does the cleric get pushed 10 feet back with the creature? What sort of sorcery of physics happens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Constrict ability happens as soon as the yuan-ti hits, and the cleric is grappled by the yuan-ti.

> ***Constrict.***
>   *Melee Weapon Attack:*
>   +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one
>   target.
>   Hit:
>   10 (2d6 + 3) bludgeoning damage, and the target is
>   grappled (escape DC 13). Until this grapple ends, the target is
>   restrained, and the yuan-ti can’t constrict another target.

The Grappled condition includes this all-important clause:

> The condition also ends if an effect removes the
>   grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or
>   grappling effect, such as when a creature is hurled
>   away by the
>   *thunderwave*
>   spell.

So when the Cleric uses Wrath of the Storm and chooses to add in the effect of Thunderbolt Strike, they will push the yuan-ti back, which will "remove the grappled creature from the reach of the grappler", and the grappled condition will end automatically.